# How do you exclude specific files from a WiX patch?

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.5

I'm using WiX's admin-image-style patch creation, but the resulting patch contains extra files that I don't want to include. My understanding of WiX patching is that it is "inclusive" by default -- that is, that you choose what to include, rather than exclude. I found [this comment](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Patch-Creation-Issues-td5923021.html#a5967383) by Peter Marcu indicating that admin patching is the way to go if you want to exclude specific files. I have a couple of questions:

1. He mentions that when you do an admin install each component is put into its own fragment -- how does this work?
2. He also says you have to use patch families (note the plural) -- what is the accepted practice for this? Do I need a ComponentRef for every component I'm including, given that they are all in individual fragments, as in (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior is to include all differences. If you don't want all, then you need to specify them individually. When you're using admin image patching, WiX creates fragments as granular as possible, so yes, you need individual ComponentRefs, BinaryRefs, etc.

Comment: Do I need to include anything special (like a heat-generated wxs) in my linker call? Or should these references auto-resolve due to the magic powers of admin patching?

Comment: No magic. All the references (e.g., ComponentRef) refer to IDs that are available in the admin image .msi so nothing else is required.